# Deserialize JSON from Riot API C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, riot-games-api

I have some problem to deserialize JSON response from the RIOT API in C#. I want to get the list of "Champion" and the API return a stream like this :

```
{  
   "type":"champion",
   "version":"6.1.1",
   "data":{  
      "Thresh":{  
         "id":412,
         "key":"Thresh",
         "name":"Thresh",
         "title":"the Chain Warden"
      },
      "Aatrox":{  
         "id":266,
         "key":"Aatrox",
         "name":"Aatrox",
         "title":"the Darkin Blade"
      },...
    }
}
```

All data has the same attributes (id, key, name and title) so I create a champion class :

```
public class Champion
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

I need your help because i dont know how to deserialize this data... I need to create a Root class with type, version and data attributes (data is a list of champion)? I watched for used NewtonSoft Json but I dont found example who helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following root object (more accurately Data Transfer Object) to retrieve the champions from the API. This will return all champions without having to create a class for each champion.

```
public class RootChampionDTO
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Champion> Data { get; set; }
}
```

then using Newtsonsoft's Json.NET, you would deserialize using the following:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootChampionDTO>(string json);
```

Comment: Just a note with Json.NET, if you aren't interested in the type or version properties, you can omit them from your `RootChampionDTO` class and it will still deserialize without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NewtonSoft:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string json);
```

Json .NET Documentation: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 0):

Consider such classes:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Version { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Champion> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Champion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And after use Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to deserialize your json:

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(json);
```

Note that Newtonsoft.Json default settings allow you to correctly parse camelCase properties from json into PascalCase properties in C# classes.